# Google Map: How to improve the accuracy of the address returned by google using reverse geocoding

Tags: android, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

We are using mobile application to track the location of the users. we have done testing of the application and found that the accuracy of the address is not correct most of the time. while testing we have also found that multiple users on the same location getting different addresses from google which is sometimes 1km away from their actual locations.

we are using reverse geocoding to get the address of the user. mobile application sends the latitude and longitude to server. server makes the reverse geocoding api call to the google and fetch the address from the google.

I want to know what we can do to improve the accuracy of the results returned by google using reverse geocoding??

Answer (score 1):

*The accuracy of the address you are getting is completely dependent on the latlng you are sending to the server. so to make it more accurate you have to send more accurate latlng to server to the result.*

you are sending the latlng from your device to your web-server and then the web-server is getting the address from google server. so this is Geo-coding.

now all you have to do is get more and more accurate latlng and send it to server to get a more accurate result.

- you are getting the latlng by two ways . network or GPS.
- so both have to be switched on prior to the operation time. so that it will get a more accurate GPS fix. you should enable GPS 30 seconds earlier then fetching the location.
- the latlng result also gets hampered if you are indoor.
- one more trick you can do is to check for the accuracy of the latlng you are getting by [getAccuracy()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) and re-request the location if you have poor accuracy.

*more information can be found here-*

[geoCoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)

Comment: i am not sending address to the server. i am sending latitude and longitude to the server and then server fetch the records from google by passing latitude and logitude using reverse geocdoing api